# Two classes with duplicates

Tags: java, spring, duplicates, code-duplication

I'm new to Java and object oriented programming. I've tried to find the solution myself, but couldn't manage to solve this problem.

I have two duplicated pieces of code which I need to remove. As I understand it, I have to create a super class for it. How can I create a super class or method in order to remove the duplicated code?:

```
public class PartnerOneService {

 public static void updatePartner(Handle handle, Long mandant, Long rID, Integer roleCd, Long lebId, String user) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
     // 1: Check if partner already exists
            Role roleInDb = roleSql.readActive(mandant, rID, roleCd);
    
            if (roleInDb == null) {
                // 2: Insert new partner 
                Process process = processCheck.get(0);
                Role role = createRole(mandant, roleCd, rID, process.getProcessId(), process.getProcessSubId(), lebId);
                roleVersioning.insert(role, TecTaskCd.MAN_REGULATION.getValue(), user, SfDate.getTimestampMilli(), ActualizationStatus.FINAL, false);
            } else {
                // 3: Update partner 
                roleInDb.setPartnerId(lebId);
                roleVersioning.insert(roleInDb, TecTaskCd.MAN_REGULATION.getValue(), user, SfDate.getTimestampMilli(), ActualizationStatus.FINAL, false);
            }
}
}

public class PartnerTwoService {
 public static void updatePartner(Handle handle, Long mandant, Long rID, Integer roleCd, Long lebId, String user) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
     // 1: Check if partner already exists
            Role roleInDb = roleSql.readActive(mandant, rID, roleCd);
    
            if (roleInDb == null) {
                // 2: Insert new partner 
                Process process = processCheck.get(0);
                Role role = createRole(mandant, roleCd, rID, process.getProcessId(), process.getProcessSubId(), lebId);
                roleVersioning.insert(role, TecTaskCd.MAN_REGULATION.getValue(), user, SfDate.getTimestampMilli(), ActualizationStatus.FINAL, false);
            } else {
                // 3: Update partner 
                roleInDb.setPartnerId(lebId);
                roleVersioning.insert(roleInDb, TecTaskCd.MAN_REGULATION.getValue(), user, SfDate.getTimestampMilli(), ActualizationStatus.FINAL, false);
            }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the code above will never compile, since you have statements outside of a block, method or constructor. First try to get compilable code before trying to improve it

Comment: Since `updatePartner` is a public, static method, you can simply call it like so: `PartnerOneService.updatePartner( ... )`. (Replace `...` with relevant method arguments.) Therefore you can safely remove the `updatePartner` method from class `PartnerTwoService`.

Comment: So you are new to Java but are directly working with complex topics that are indicated here, e.g. db access, versioning, services etc.? Why don't you grab a Java tutorial first and work your way through at least the polymorphism/inheritance portion?

Comment: @Thomas I am a frontend person but have to do some backend stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create third service like RolePartnerService and put this code in where. Then you need to set roles partner you can call it like

```
rolePartnerService.setRole(mandant, rID, roleCd); //and whatever arguments you need
```